# How do I get eclipse to compile and copy only .java files during build?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a dynamic web project in eclipse (although I'm not using it as a web project.  I would like to convert it to a java project if possible) and there are java files all over the place. There are also a lot of other files like images etc (which I don't want to remove because the project is linked to my SVN repo so if i do an update then everything will come back).

Now when i build my project eclipse copies all the files instead of compiling and copying the .java files only and this takes a lot of time because there are some 2GB worth of files.

I tried to include only .java files in the source by going to properties of my project -> Java Build Path -> source tab -> includes -> I added "*.java" to the textbox. However, no file got copied to my output folder after that.

how do i go about this? Deleting the images etc from my project is not a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Add `**/*.java/` in the includes.